# Laravel relation with types

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have tried to find the best solution for my problem without getting exactly what i want.

I have 4 tables now, the structure looks like this.

```
:: Users ::
id
name
email
------

:: user_equipment ::
id
user_id
equipment_id
equipment_type

:: weapons ::
id
name
price

:: armor ::
id
name
price
```

My goal is to be able to use my relations like this:

```
$user->equipment
$user->equipment->weapons
$user->equipment->armor
```

Here is what i have right now:

User Model:

```
class User extends Model
{    
  public function equipment()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(UserEquipment::class);
  }
}
```

UserEquipment Model:

```
class UserEquipment extends Model
{
   public function weapons()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Weapon::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: does each `user` has only one `weapon` and one `armor`?

Comment: @Capt.Teemo No user will be able to have a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `User` model and `UserEquipment` model has the same class name.

Try this, change your `user` model to

```
public function weapons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Weapon', 'equipment_id')->where('equipment_type','weapon'); //second paramater tells what column to relate the id
} 

public function armors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Armors', 'equipment_id')->where('equipment_type','armor'); 
}
```

Then here's how you query:

```
User::with('weapons', 'armors')->get();
```

Comment: Could you explain how this would work, i am now trying to call User::with('weapons')->get(); and i am just getting column not found for weapons. equipment_id. With the user model you provide there is no connection to the user_equipments table right ? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this will work. From where the Armor/Weapon models get the 'equipment_id' if you are bypassing the 'user_equipment' table?

Comment: try changing `hasMany` to `belongsToMany` if you are using `many to many` relationship

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a [Many To Many Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

In your case, you'll need to define your relationships this way:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the weapons owned by the user.
     */
    public function weapons()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Weapon', 'equipment', 'user_equipment');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the armors owned by the user.
     */
    public function armors()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Armor', 'equipment', 'user_equipment');
    }
}
```

Doing your queries:

```php
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->weapons as $weapon) {
    //
}

foreach ($user->armors as $armor) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this is on the right track of what i am in need of. However this resulted in an empty collection so something is not right. Can it perhaps be the database names that doesn't connect with the classes or etc?

Comment: I updated the relatinships definition adding a third argument: `user_equipment`, this tells laravel the name of the table to look the relationship. I also linked the documentation at the top of the answer to give you a clearer explanation of how this works. The part that will interest you is the "Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship" of that section.

Comment: i've read the documentation, still no success. The table names seems to be right but i think code placement is a bit off. Thanks, please provide more help if u can

Comment: @DilleFepp sure. Just add the details of your tables and models. Maybe its something wrong in those files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your tables like this:

```
:: Users ::
id
name
email
------

:: user_equipment ::
id
user_id
equipment_type

:: weapons ::
id
name
price
user_equipment_id

:: armor ::
id
name
price
user_equipment_id
```

Then you can use the functions as you were using them:
User Model:

```
class User extends Model
{    
  public function equipment()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(UserEquipment::class);
  }
}
```

UserEquipment Model:

```
class UserEquipment extends Model
{
   public function weapons()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Weapon::class);
   }
   public function armor()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Armor::class);
   }
}
```

Notice in laravel Documentation that Laravel assumes in the Model `Weapons` there would be a foreign key call `user_equipment_id`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: I see, the issue here is that i am not really intrested in populating the weapons and armor tables with user specific items. I wish to only use the relation table so i can keep it clean.